# How to destroy camel component and corresponding Endpoint, Producer and Consumer?

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce

I am trying to completely destroy a camel component. But the available option is to remove the camel component from the camel context, i.e. camelContext.removeComponent(componentName). But after removing the camel component from the camel context, the corresponding Endpoint, Producer and Consumer did not get destroy and when I re-created the Camel Component, it is still using the old Producer, Consumer and Endpoint. How do I completely destroy it so that once I recreate the component, it also creates new Producer, Consumer and Endpoint.

One of the use cases: We are connecting to Salesforce using apache camel to fetch metadata. Once the credentials to connect the salesforce changes/expired we need to destroy the old Salesforce component and create a new Salesforce component. We need to do this dynamically without restarting the camel context or the JVM. But once we remove the component from camel context it only destroys the Component  but corresponding Endpoint, Producer, Processors, Consumers remains the same, consequentely the HTTP client of the Processor(JsonRestProcessor) remains the same which is different from the HTTP client of the newly created Salesforce component. Aslo when we remove the component and cerate the new component, then it creates the new HTTP client but the Processor(JsonRestProcessor) still refers to the old HTTP client. The old HTTP client sometimes goes to STOPPED state and our call to Salesforce fails. And when we try to start the HTTP cleint using "salesforceComponent.getConfig().getHttpClient().start()", it actuallty start the new HTTP client which is not used to connect to the Salesforce when we make a call to Salesforce. And since old HTTP client is in STOPPED state, any subsequent call to the salesforce fails.

Comment: what is your reason/use-case for doing this

Comment: Added one use case in the question itself.

Comment: Another Use case : We do not want to keep Salesforce connection open after call to Salesforce is completed so we stop the component. Once we stop the component it destroy the HTTP client(but it does not remove the same object from the Processor(JsonRestProcessor)).Once we re-start the component it create a new HTTP client but HTTP client in Processor(JsonRestProcessor) remains old one. So we do not have any way to start the old component once it STOPPED and this old HTTP client is used to connect to the Salesforce and if it STOPPED then calls to Salesfroce using salesforce component fails.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Is there anything can be done to achieve this?

Comment: You would need to get all the endpoints, and routes where you use salesforce  and stop and remove them also via the API on CamelContext. Maybe a better alternative is to create a new CamelContext per update and then shutdown the old one.